# Can I create Oracle Database Link for ASM?

Tags: oracle, dblink

I want to access ASM externally via Database Link from Oracle Single Instance. To connect ASM, I need to access there as SYSDBA or SYSASM (Thats what I know). Is there any way to create Database Link with connecting as SYS priv. such as SYSASM or  SYSDBA?
I tried this and did not work.

```
Create database link test
connect to user identified by userpwd as SYSASM
using 'orcl';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is easy: **you can't**

Let me explain you why.

ASM or Automatic Storage Management is an instance for handling storage devices such as disks, disk-groups or filesystems such as ACFS.

> Oracle ASM is a volume manager and a file system for Oracle database
> files that supports single-instance Oracle Database and Oracle Real
> Application Clusters (Oracle RAC) configurations. Oracle ASM is
> Oracle's recommended storage management solution that provides an
> alternative to conventional volume managers, file systems, and raw
> devices.

When you connect to ASM you do it to handle these topics. A `database link` is a way to connect to remote objects as tables, views, procedures which reside in a different and remote database, and perform operations with them in your local database.

**ASM is just an instance, not a database**, therefore you can't connect to it that way. You must connect from the server ( locally ) or you can have a listener with a service to the ASM instance and set of steps to be able to connect remotely. In this case you connect to ASM as you were connecting to a Database.

Read this post

[http://www.dbaref.com/asm-quick-ref/howtoconnecttoasminstancefromaremoteclient](http://Connect%20remotely%20to%20ASM)